# Function is executed after code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath even if it's not supposed to

Tags: ios

My `tableView` function :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("VIDEOPLAY AT RUNTIME 3 BLANK \(self.videoPlay)")

    jsonRequestSecond("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2C+contentDetails&maxResults=30&playlistId=UUxEMA4apFhleO3ONQTowMvQ&key=AIzaSyBukkCFuaUubyP7lkP1UAkyS6jS25u5AaQ", indexx: indexPath.row)

    print("VIDEOPLAY AT RUNTIME 2 \(self.videoPlay)")

    let youtubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoPlay)"

    self.youtubeView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

    self.youtubeView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(self.youtubeView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(self.youtubeView.frame.height)\" src=\"\(youtubeUrl)?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen scrolling=no></iframe>", baseURL: nil)


    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And I have this one:

```
func jsonRequestSecond(urlString: String, indexx: Int) {

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

    session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            if let responseData = data {
                do {

                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)

                    if let dict = json as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        // Get the first dictionary item from the returned items (usually there's just one item).

                        // self.nextPgToken = dict["nextPageToken"] as! String!
                        // print(self.nextPgToken)
                        // self.tableView.reloadData()

                        let items: AnyObject! = dict["items"] as AnyObject!
                        let items2: Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>> = dict["items"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>

                        let firstItemDict = (items as! Array<AnyObject>)[indexx] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                        // Get the snippet dictionary that contains the desired data.
                        let snippetDict = firstItemDict["snippet"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                        let contentDict = firstItemDict["contentDetails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                        // Create a new dictionary to store only the values I care about.
                        var desiredValuesDict: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>()
                        // print(snippetDict)

                        /***********/
                        // print(contentDict["videoId"]!)


                        print(contentDict["videoId"]! as! String)
                        print(contentDict.count)
                        self.videoPlay = contentDict["videoId"]! as! String
                        print("VIDEOPLAY AT RUNTIME 1 \(self.videoPlay)")
                        return;


                        /***********/
                        desiredValuesDict["title"] = snippetDict["title"]
                        desiredValuesDict["description"] = snippetDict["description"]
                        desiredValuesDict["thumbnail"] = ((snippetDict["thumbnails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["default"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["url"]
                        // Save the channel's uploaded videos playlist ID.
                        // desiredValuesDict["playlistID"] = ((firstItemDict["contentDetails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["relatedPlaylists"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["uploads"]
                        // Append the desiredValuesDict dictionary to the following array.
                        self.channelsDataArray.append(desiredValuesDict)
                        // self.videosIDArray.append(desiredValuesDict)

                        print("TESTING **************************")
                        // Use a loop to go through all video items.
                        for var i=0; i<items2.count; ++i {
                            let playlistSnippetDict = (items2[i] as Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["snippet"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                            // Initialize a new dictionary and store the data of interest.
                            var desiredPlaylistItemDataDict = Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>()
                            desiredPlaylistItemDataDict["title"] = playlistSnippetDict["title"]
                            // print(desiredPlaylistItemDataDict["title"])
                            desiredPlaylistItemDataDict["thumbnail"] = ((playlistSnippetDict["thumbnails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["default"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["url"]
                            // print(desiredPlaylistItemDataDict["thumbnail"])
                            desiredPlaylistItemDataDict["videoId"] = (playlistSnippetDict["resourceId"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["videoId"]
                            // print(desiredPlaylistItemDataDict["videoID"])
                            // Append the desiredPlaylistItemDataDict dictionary to the videos array.
                            self.videosArray.append(desiredPlaylistItemDataDict)
                            self.videosIDArray.addObject(contentDict["videoId"]! as! String)
                            // self.videoPlay = contentDict["videoId"]! as! String
                            self.tableView.reloadData()

                            /*

                            */
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Could not serialize")
                }

            }
        })
        }.resume()
}
```

Here is my output:

```
2016-01-21 23:35:49.623 Project[4225:125152] Could not load the "videos-playlists" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.company.project"

pjrr60geles
1
TESTING **************************
VIDEOPLAY AT RUNTIME 3 BLANK 
VIDEOPLAY AT RUNTIME 2 
YW7qrbtcVEE
1
VIDEOPLAY AT RUNTIME 1 YW7qrbtcVEE
```

Do you see my point? 
I've first called `jsonRequestSecond` and then

```
print("VIDEOPLAY AT RUNTIME 2 \(self.videoPlay)").
```

Shouldn't I get the opposite?

Comment: The code in your `jsonRequestSecond` function is running in the background.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought so. But, that is causing me problems. For example, i select one of my cells and then at the top my `UIWebView` is populated with that link the song has in YouTube. So, when I click on one cell, `UIWebView` is empty. And then, when I click on second cell, the view is populated with the previous link. Any ideas, solutions?

Comment: This is a common issue and with some searching you should be able to find plenty of examples and solutions. At a high level, you need to pass a completion handler to `jsonRequestSecond`. You update the table in that completion handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jsonRequestSecond` method calls out to `NSURLSession.dataTaskWithURL` with your print statement in a completion block that then calls `dispatch_async` so your print statement won't get called until after the dataTask finishes.

This code isn't linear, so it won't get executed linearly.

Comment: Is this a quick fix? If it is, can you provide me the best possible way of doing that?

Comment: If you need the code to execute _after_ the data task has finished, you need to put that code into a place it will get called by the data task's completion handler. One suggestion is to add a completion handler to `jsonRequestSecond` that does the work you need. So in your case, you'd put the calls that you now have after `jsonRequestSecond` into the completion handler instead. Then, the final thing you do in the data task completion handler is to call the completion handler passed in to `jsonRequestSecond`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull out the jsonRequestSecond block and make a custom method out of it, this custom method should have a protocol method that you call in your UIViewcontroller where the tableView is.

iOS isn't going to hang up the UI to load data from a URL. That's bad practice. You're only supposed to dispatch to main queue for UI elements.